# Generating all combinations of items (including duplicates) from an array of options in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently building a tool where the user can select 3 flavours of ice cream. They get 3 scoops and can choose either a single flavour, or a combination of any three.

Eg. [Vanilla, Vanilla, Vanilla], [Vanilla, Chocolate, Strawberry], [Vanilla, Chocolate, Chocolate] etc.

I need to create an object of all the various options to map them to a specific SKU.

eg.

```
const combos = {
  "SCOOPS-VVV": ['Vanilla', 'Vanilla', 'Vanilla'],
  "SCOOPS-VVC": ['Vanilla', 'Vanilla', 'Chocolate'],
  "SCOOPS-VCC": ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Chocolate'],
}
```

I have 9 flavours and will probably have more in the future so ideally I want to generate this object programatically - I have a solution but it doesn't feel very performant as I'm using nested `for` loops. see here:

```
for (let i = 0; i < flavours.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < flavours.length; j++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < flavours.length; k++) {
      const flavoursCombo = [flavours[i], flavours[j], flavours[k]]
      // ...check for duplicates then add each combo to the combos object.
    }
  }
}
```

There's a good chance I'll have an option to choose between 3, 4 or 5  scoops in the future as well so then this approach will be even worse.

Any improvement on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not response but is it not easier to create combo name after user selected flavours ?

ex : user select ['Vanilla', 'Vanilla', 'Vanilla'] in your tool and you can generate name after by selecting first letter of flavour SCOOPS-{flavours[0].charAt(0), flavours[1].charAt(0), flavours[2].charAt(0)}...

Comment: @Loic Yes sorry, that is how i'm doing it, just didn't include that bit. I'm more concerned with the generation of all the combinations.

Answer (score 1):

I would have opted for a recursive function instead of multiple `for` loops. Here is an idea.

```
function createFlavorCombinations(flavors) {
  const combinations = {};
  let id = 1;
  
  function generateCombinations(flavors, combination) {
    if (combination.length === flavors.length) {
      combinations[`SCOOPS-${id}`] = combination;
      id++;
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
        const newCombination = [...combination, flavors[i]];
        generateCombinations(flavors, newCombination);
      }
    }
  }
  
  generateCombinations(flavors, []);
  return combinations;
}
```

A few notes:

1. We the recursive function, you don't need to worry about multiple `for` loops and you can have a dynamic size of input.
2. I changed the object keys method you have with the initials to a unique ID instead. What if you have two flavours in the future with the same initial? Then you will end up overwriting the values of the previous one.
3. I tested it with 3 and 4 combinations. I haven't timed it but generally speaking, it was fast.
4. I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/930cjyop/) with it where you can play around and see it in action

You can call the function like this

```
const flavors_3 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
const combinations_3 = createFlavorCombinations(flavors_3);
console.log(combinations_3);
```

The output will be as:

```
{
  SCOOPS-1: ["A", "A", "A"],
  SCOOPS-10: ["B", "A", "A"],
  SCOOPS-11: ["B", "A", "B"],
  SCOOPS-12: ["B", "A", "C"],
  SCOOPS-13: ["B", "B", "A"],
  SCOOPS-14: ["B", "B", "B"],
  SCOOPS-15: ["B", "B", "C"],
  SCOOPS-16: ["B", "C", "A"],
  SCOOPS-17: ["B", "C", "B"],
  SCOOPS-18: ["B", "C", "C"],
  SCOOPS-19: ["C", "A", "A"],
  SCOOPS-2: ["A", "A", "B"],
  SCOOPS-20: ["C", "A", "B"],
  SCOOPS-21: ["C", "A", "C"],
  SCOOPS-22: ["C", "B", "A"],
  SCOOPS-23: ["C", "B", "B"],
  SCOOPS-24: ["C", "B", "C"],
  SCOOPS-25: ["C", "C", "A"],
  SCOOPS-26: ["C", "C", "B"],
  SCOOPS-27: ["C", "C", "C"],
  SCOOPS-3: ["A", "A", "C"],
  SCOOPS-4: ["A", "B", "A"],
  SCOOPS-5: ["A", "B", "B"],
  SCOOPS-6: ["A", "B", "C"],
  SCOOPS-7: ["A", "C", "A"],
  SCOOPS-8: ["A", "C", "B"],
  SCOOPS-9: ["A", "C", "C"]
}
```

Comment: that's definitely a better approach. Not quite what I'm looking for as I need the arrays to be 3 in length regardless of how many flavours I have (yours currently outputs combinations of however many flavours there are) but it's a great starting block for me, so thanks! Sidenote: when i tested this with 9 flavours, my chrome crashed so there may be a leak somewhere?

Comment: I apologise. When you mentioned that you might increase the number of scoops in the future to 4 or 5, I thought it will follow the same logic.

Comment: Ah yeah my bad, It's more that more scoops would be an option, but i'd still need the 3 combo, 4 combo etc.